# How can cabbage worms (Pieris brassicae) smell/see cabbages from a distance?

Tags: zoology, entomology

Recently I did post a [question on gardening stackexchange](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/36196/can-cabbage-worms-pieris-brassicae-smell-cabbages-from-a-distance) asking if cabbage worms could smell their way back into my cabbages after I moved them away outside my fence. Answers says yes they do, but it seemed to me opinion-based and I cant find anything to support this answers.

Can this type of worm smell/see or have any other type of sensorial navigation thing that can lead them towards cabbages?

Comment: Yes, caterpillars have [antennae that provide an olfactory sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar#Description). I don't know how well this particular caterpillar can smell and if it can travel long distances, but it is able to identify its food source.

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking about the caterpillar? The most important way the caterpillar ends up at your plant is because the butterflies deposit their eggs.